# Angular Select Options with image

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-select2

I want select drop down option with respective images ,can anyone help me in this ,
here is my code

```
<select  class="form-control demo-htmlselect" 
         ng-model="spList"  
         ng-options="spList.name for spList in spDTOList" 
         required>
    <option disabled selected>Select Option</option>
</select>
```

Here I want get the options with images, I want to use pure angularjs,

can anyone help me to use select2 with angular js
[Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We Can achieve this using select2 templating with angular, select2-ui for angular helps to design [select2-angular](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this guy. He seems to have built something similair to what you want
http://yairnevet.blogspot.dk/2013/02/multiple-select-drop-down-list-using.html

EDIT: It was pointed out to me (and i can see now when i see the code) that he indeed uses jquery to achieve what he easily could have done with angular alone. I still think the example serveres as a demonstration. The trick here is not use the default `SELECT` tag of html but instead style an `UL` with `LI`'s to get the desired result.

Comment: That one has jQuery dependency. :(

Comment: @petur it was ment as an inspiration. The jquery part could easily be modified to vanilla js instead...

Comment: Thanks for taking time and checking this question 2 years later

Comment: @petur see you again in a couple of years ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, i've used github iconselect project built on pure javascript, so you can add it to your project and invoke it from the angular controller. Check here for seeing it working. http://jsfiddle.net/Vsgyf/1/

HTML:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" ng:autobind
> src="http://code.angularjs.org/0.10.4/angular-0.10.4.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://bug7a.github.io/iconselect.js/sample/lib/iscroll.js"></script>
> <div ng:controller="Ctrl"> 
>
>     <div id="my-icon-select"></div>   
>
> </div>
> ```

JS:

```
function Ctrl() {

    this.list = [
        { name:'SWISS', img:'http://s9.postimage.org/d9t33we17/Swiss.png'},
        {name:'UNITED', img:'http://s9.postimage.org/ykqn85w5n/United.png'},
        {name:'KLM', img:'http://s9.postimage.org/p7unhshsb/Klm.png'},
        {name:'EL AL', img:'http://s18.postimage.org/oi8ndntud/image.gif'},
        {name:'Ethiopian', img:'http://s9.postimage.org/hqlg2ks97/image.gif'}
    ];


    iconSelect = new IconSelect("my-icon-select");
    var icons = [];
    for(var i = 0; i< this.list.length; i++){
     icons.push({'iconFilePath': this.list[i].img, 'iconValue':this.list[i].name});
    }
    iconSelect.refresh(icons);                                                   

};



IconSelect.DEFAULT = {};
IconSelect.DEFAULT.SELECTED_ICON_WIDTH = 48;
IconSelect.DEFAULT.SELECTED_ICON_HEIGHT = 48;
IconSelect.DEFAULT.SELECTED_BOX_PADDING = 1;
IconSelect.DEFAULT.SELECTED_BOX_PADDING_RIGHT = 12;
IconSelect.DEFAULT.ICONS_WIDTH = 32;
IconSelect.DEFAULT.ICONS_HEIGHT = 32;
IconSelect.DEFAULT.BOX_ICON_SPACE = 1;
IconSelect.DEFAULT.HORIZONTAL_ICON_NUMBER = 3;
IconSelect.DEFAULT.VECTORAL_ICON_NUMBER = 3;

IconSelect.COMPONENT_ICON_FILE_PATH = "http://bug7a.github.io/iconselect.js/sample/images/control/icon-select/arrow.png";

function IconSelect($$elementID, $$parameters) {

    var _icons = [];
    var _selectedIndex = -1;
    var _boxScroll;

    var _default = IconSelect.DEFAULT;

    function _init() {

        //parametreler boÅŸ gelirse
        if(!$$parameters) $$parameters = {};

        if(_View.setIconSelectElement($$elementID)){

            //set parameters
            $$parameters = _Model.checkParameters($$parameters);
            //create UI
            var ui = _View.createUI($$parameters, $$elementID);

            _View.iconSelectElement.onclick = function(){
                _View.showBox();
            };


            _View.showBox(false);


            _View.iconSelectElement.addEventListener('click', function($event){
                $event.stopPropagation();             
            });


            window.addEventListener('click', function(){
                _View.showBox(false);
            });

        }else{
            alert("Element not found.");
        }

    }


    this.refresh = function($icons){

        _icons = [];

        var setSelectedIndex = this.setSelectedIndex;

        for(var i = 0; i < $icons.length; i++){
            $icons[i].element = _View.createIcon($icons[i].iconFilePath, $icons[i].iconValue, i, $$parameters);
            $icons[i].element.onclick = function(){
                setSelectedIndex(this.childNodes[0].getAttribute('icon-index'));

            };
            _icons.push($icons[i]);

        }

        var horizontalIconNumber = Math.round(($icons.length) / $$parameters.vectoralIconNumber);

        _View.boxElement.style.height = (($$parameters.iconsHeight + 2) * horizontalIconNumber) + 
                ((horizontalIconNumber + 1) * $$parameters.boxIconSpace);
        this.setSelectedIndex(0);

    };

    //icon listesini al.
    this.getIcons = function(){ return _icons; };

    //iconu seÃ§ili hale gelir.
    this.setSelectedIndex = function($index){

        var icon;

        if(_icons.length > $index)
            icon = _icons[$index];

        if(icon){
            if(_selectedIndex != -1) _icons[_selectedIndex].element.setAttribute('class','icon');
            _selectedIndex = $index;
            _View.selectedIconImgElement.setAttribute('src', icon.iconFilePath);
            if(_selectedIndex != -1) _icons[_selectedIndex].element.setAttribute('class','icon selected');
        }

        _View.iconSelectElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('changed'));


    };

    this.getSelectedIndex = function(){ return _selectedIndex; };
    this.getSelectedValue = function(){ return _icons[_selectedIndex].iconValue };
    this.getSelectedFilePath = function(){ return _icons[_selectedIndex].iconFilePath };



    //### VIEW CLASS ###

    function _View(){}

    _View.iconSelectElement;
    _View.boxElement;
    _View.boxScrollElement;
    _View.selectedIconImgElement;
    _View.selectedIconElement;

    _View.showBox = function($isShown){

         if($isShown == null) {
             $isShown = (_View.boxElement.style.display == "none") ? true : false;
         }

        if($isShown) {
            _View.boxElement.style.display = "block";
            _View.boxScrollElement.style.display = "block";
            _boxScroll = (_boxScroll) ? _boxScroll : new iScroll($$elementID + "-box-scroll");
        }else{
            _View.boxElement.style.display = "none";
            _View.boxScrollElement.style.display = "none";
        }

        _View.boxElement.style.display = ($isShown) ? "block" : "none";



    };

    _View.setIconSelectElement = function($elementID){
        _View.iconSelectElement = document.getElementById($elementID);
        return _View.iconSelectElement;
    };

    _View.clearUI = function(){
        _View.iconSelectElement.innerHTML = "";
    };

    _View.clearIcons = function(){
        _View.boxElement.innerHTML = "";
    };

    _View.createUI = function($parameters){

        /* HTML MODEL

        <div id="my-icon-select" class="icon-select">
            <div class="selected-box">
                <div class="selected-icon"><img src="images/icons/i2.png"></div>
                <div class="component-icon"><img src="images/control/icon-select/arrow.png"></div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="icon"><img src="images/icons/i1.png"></div>
                    <div class="icon selected"><img src="images/icons/i2.png"></div>
                    <div class="icon"><img src="images/icons/i3.png"></div>
                    <div class="icon"><img src="images/icons/i4.png"></div>
                    <div class="icon"><img src="images/icons/i3.png"></div>
                    <div class="icon"><img src="images/icons/i4.png"></div>
                    <div class="icon"><img src="images/icons/i5.png"></div>
                    <div class="icon"><img src="images/icons/i6.png"></div>
                    <div class="icon"><img src="images/icons/i7.png"></div>
                    <div class="icon"><img src="images/icons/i8.png"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        */

        _View.clearUI();

        _View.iconSelectElement.setAttribute('class', 'icon-select');

        var selectedBoxElement = document.createElement('div');
        selectedBoxElement.setAttribute('class' ,'selected-box');

        var selectedIconElement = document.createElement('div');
        selectedIconElement.setAttribute('class' ,'selected-icon');

        _View.selectedIconImgElement = document.createElement('img');
        _View.selectedIconImgElement.setAttribute('src', '');
        selectedIconElement.appendChild(_View.selectedIconImgElement);

        var componentIconElement = document.createElement('div');
        componentIconElement.setAttribute('class', 'component-icon');

        var componentIconImgElement = document.createElement('img');
        componentIconImgElement.setAttribute('src', IconSelect.COMPONENT_ICON_FILE_PATH );
        componentIconElement.appendChild(componentIconImgElement);

        _View.boxScrollElement = document.createElement('div');
        _View.boxScrollElement.setAttribute('id',$$elementID + "-box-scroll");
        _View.boxScrollElement.setAttribute('class', 'box');

        _View.boxElement = document.createElement('div');

        _View.boxScrollElement.appendChild(_View.boxElement);

        _View.selectedIconImgElement.setAttribute('width', $parameters.selectedIconWidth);
        _View.selectedIconImgElement.setAttribute('height', $parameters.selectedIconHeight);
        selectedIconElement.style.width = $parameters.selectedIconWidth;
        selectedIconElement.style.height = $parameters.selectedIconHeight;
        selectedBoxElement.style.width = $parameters.selectedIconWidth + $parameters.selectedBoxPadding + $parameters.selectedBoxPaddingRight;
        selectedBoxElement.style.height = $parameters.selectedIconHeight + ($parameters.selectedBoxPadding * 2);
        selectedIconElement.style.top = $parameters.selectedBoxPadding;
        selectedIconElement.style.left = $parameters.selectedBoxPadding;
        componentIconElement.style.bottom = 4 + $parameters.selectedBoxPadding;

        _View.boxScrollElement.style.left = parseInt(selectedBoxElement.style.width) + 1;

        _View.boxScrollElement.style.width = (($parameters.iconsWidth + 2) * $parameters.vectoralIconNumber) + 
                (($parameters.vectoralIconNumber + 1) * $parameters.boxIconSpace);
        _View.boxScrollElement.style.height = (($parameters.iconsHeight + 2) * $parameters.horizontalIconNumber) + 
                (($parameters.horizontalIconNumber + 1) * $parameters.boxIconSpace);

        _View.boxElement.style.left = _View.boxScrollElement.style.left;
        _View.boxElement.style.width = _View.boxScrollElement.style.width;

        _View.iconSelectElement.appendChild(selectedBoxElement);
        selectedBoxElement.appendChild(selectedIconElement);
        selectedBoxElement.appendChild(componentIconElement);
        selectedBoxElement.appendChild(_View.boxScrollElement);


        var results = {};
        results['iconSelectElement'] = _View.iconSelectElement;
        results['selectedBoxElement'] = selectedBoxElement;
        results['selectedIconElement'] = selectedIconElement;
        results['selectedIconImgElement'] = _View.selectedIconImgElement;
        results['componentIconElement'] = componentIconElement;
        results['componentIconImgElement'] = componentIconImgElement;

        return results;


    };

    _View.createIcon = function($iconFilePath, $iconValue, $index, $parameters){



        var iconElement = document.createElement('div');
        iconElement.setAttribute('class', 'icon');
        iconElement.style.width = $parameters.iconsWidth;
        iconElement.style.height = $parameters.iconsHeight;
        iconElement.style.marginLeft = $parameters.boxIconSpace;
        iconElement.style.marginTop = $parameters.boxIconSpace;

        var iconImgElement = document.createElement('img');
        iconImgElement.setAttribute('src', $iconFilePath);
        iconImgElement.setAttribute('icon-value', $iconValue);
        iconImgElement.setAttribute('icon-index', $index);
        iconImgElement.setAttribute('width', $parameters.iconsWidth);
        iconImgElement.setAttribute('height', $parameters.iconsHeight);

        iconElement.appendChild(iconImgElement);
        _View.boxElement.appendChild(iconElement);

        return iconElement;

    };

    //### MODEL CLASS ###

    function _Model(){}

    //TODO: params deÄŸiÅŸkenini kaldÄ±r yeni oluÅŸtursun.
    _Model.checkParameters = function($parameters){

        $parameters.selectedIconWidth          = ($parameters.selectedIconWidth)          ? $parameters.selectedIconWidth        : _default.SELECTED_ICON_WIDTH;
        $parameters.selectedIconHeight         = ($parameters.selectedIconHeight)         ? $parameters.selectedIconHeight       : _default.SELECTED_ICON_HEIGHT;
        $parameters.selectedBoxPadding         = ($parameters.selectedBoxPadding)         ? $parameters.selectedBoxPadding       : _default.SELECTED_BOX_PADDING;
        $parameters.selectedBoxPaddingRight    = ($parameters.selectedBoxPaddingRight)    ? $parameters.selectedBoxPaddingRight  : _default.SELECTED_BOX_PADDING_RIGHT;
        $parameters.iconsWidth                 = ($parameters.iconsWidth)                 ? $parameters.iconsWidth               : _default.ICONS_WIDTH;
        $parameters.iconsHeight                = ($parameters.iconsHeight)                ? $parameters.iconsHeight              : _default.ICONS_HEIGHT;
        $parameters.boxIconSpace               = ($parameters.boxIconSpace)               ? $parameters.boxIconSpace             : _default.BOX_ICON_SPACE;
        $parameters.vectoralIconNumber         = ($parameters.vectoralIconNumber)         ? $parameters.vectoralIconNumber       : _default.VECTORAL_ICON_NUMBER;
        $parameters.horizontalIconNumber       = ($parameters.horizontalIconNumber)       ? $parameters.horizontalIconNumber     : _default.HORIZONTAL_ICON_NUMBER;

        return $parameters;

    };

    _init();

}
```

CSS:

```
 .icon-select{
    width:0px;
 }

 .icon-select .selected-box {

     position: relative;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     width: 70px; /* sil */
     height: 60px; /* sil */
     border: 1px solid #999999;

     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     border-radius: 3px;

 }

 .icon-select .selected-box:hover {

     position: relative;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     width: 70px; /* sil */
     height: 60px; /* sil */
     border: 1px solid #000000;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;

     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     border-radius: 3px;

 }

 .icon-select .selected-icon {

     position: absolute;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     top:5px;
     left:5px;
     width: 48px; /* sil */
     height: 48px; /* sil */

     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     border-radius: 3px;

 }

 .icon-select .component-icon{
     position: absolute;
     bottom:5px;
     right:4px;
 }

 .icon-select .box {

     position: absolute;
     top:0px;
     left:71px;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     width: 170px; /* sil */
     height: 170px; /* sil */
     border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
     background-color: #EEEEEE;

     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     border-radius: 3px;


     overflow:auto;
     /*
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
     */

 }

 .icon-select .icon {
     position: relative;
     margin: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
     padding: 0px;
     width: 48px; /* sil */
     height: 48px; /* sil */
     border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;

     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     border-radius: 3px;

     overflow:hidden;
     float: left;
 }

 .icon-select .icon:hover {
     border: 1px solid #000000;
 }

 .icon-select .icon.selected {
     position: relative;
     margin: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
     padding: 0px;
     width: 48px; /* sil */
     height: 48px; /* sil */
     border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
     background-color: #EEEEEE;

     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     border-radius: 3px;

     overflow:hidden;
     float: left;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response and explanation but i am not satisfied with this, actually we can do it by using select2 angularjs plugin , unfortunately I am unable to use this http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/, can u pls help me to use this

Answer (score 2):

You could use angular-strap select.I believe thats better than going through the confusing documentation of select2
http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##selects

Answer (score 1):

Checkout a example at **[angularjs select option with custom format value](http://angularjsaz.blogspot.com/2015/11/angularjs-select-option-with-image.html)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Having style inside select boxes is very restricted. You can infact not use images, or webfonts inside select boxes. It is restricted from the browser. Imagine what would happen if a cell-phone or tablet which usually have the OS's custom dropdown, that would screw up everything.

Your only option is to go with a custom directive for example angular-dropdowns.

https://github.com/jseppi/angular-dropdowns

I have used it in some projects and it is fairy easy to style and you can include both images and webfonts.